# How to convert number to date format?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, date, oracle11g

I want to convert the number to date format. how to convert in oracle?
Example: i have time key column(data type number) and want to create new columns as date

```
Time Key       Date
2018030100     01-Mar-2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want `to_date()`?

Assuming that the last two digits are always `00`:

```
select to_date(my number / 100, 'yyyymmdd') as mydate 
from mytable
```

Or if they can have other values, but you always want to ignore them:

```
select to_date(round(my number / 100), 'yyyymmdd') as mydate 
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of to_date and trim function.

```
select to_char(to_date(trim( trailing '0' from '2018030100'),'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-mon-yyyy') from dual;
```

If you have number field then you can:

```
select to_char(to_date(trim( trailing '0' from id),'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-mon-yyyy') from test_date;
```